# How to create RedisCacheManager in spring-data 3.0.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis-cache, cachemanager

I'm migrating my application from spring boot 1.5.x to 3.0.x. I want to keep jedis but I have a problem with the instantiation of `RedisCacheManager`.

Now constructor signature is

> ```
> RedisCacheManager(RedisCacheWriter cacheWriter, RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfiguration)
> ```
>
> But before it was:

```
RedisCacheManager(RedisOperations redisOperations)
```

I define this bean having only `RedisTemplate` in scope:

```
@Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager1(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
        cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(300);
        HashMap<String, Long> expires = new HashMap<>();
        expires.put("DELIVERED_DLR_MESSAGE_PART_COUNT_MAP", new Long(1000));
        expires.put("FAILED_DLR_MESSAGE_PART_COUNT_MAP", new Long(1000));
        cacheManager.setExpires(expires);
        cacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);

        return cacheManager;
    }
```

How is it supposed to be created now?